# WordPress Throwing Deprecated Errors on its own Files

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, debug, deprecation

My WordPress Website is throwing PHP Deprecated Errors on wp-include files.

I am novice WordPress Developer working on my site.

I am being flooded by these errors and extremely high CPU consumption on my site. Activating a specific set of plugins results in Deprecated Error in my WordPress installation.

I am using PHP7.4, and have experienced the same on PHP 8.1 as well.

Since these errors origniate from wp-includes folder I suspect WordPress is trying to tell me something that I am not understanding.

Secondly, what the hell is this "Cookie Jar"?

```
[16-Mar-2023 18:08:11 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Requests_Cookie_Jar::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in public_html/wp-includes/Requests/Cookie/Jar.php on line 63
[16-Mar-2023 18:08:11 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Requests_Cookie_Jar::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in public_html/wp-includes/Requests/Cookie/Jar.php on line 73
[16-Mar-2023 18:08:11 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Requests_Cookie_Jar::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in public_html/wp-includes/Requests/Cookie/Jar.php on line 89
[16-Mar-2023 18:08:11 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Requests_Cookie_Jar::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in public_html/wp-includes/Requests/Cookie/Jar.php on line 102
[16-Mar-2023 18:08:11 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Requests_Cookie_Jar::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in public_html/wp-includes/Requests/Cookie/Jar.php on line 111
[16-Mar-2023 18:08:12 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in public_html/wp-includes/Requests/Utility/CaseInsensitiveDictionary.php on line 40
[16-Mar-2023 18:08:12 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in public_html/wp-includes/Requests/Utility/CaseInsensitiveDictionary.php on line 51
[16-Mar-2023 18:08:12 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in public_html/wp-includes/Requests/Utility/CaseInsensitiveDictionary.php on line 68
[16-Mar-2023 18:08:12 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in public_html/wp-includes/Requests/Utility/CaseInsensitiveDictionary.php on line 82
[16-Mar-2023 18:08:12 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in public_html/wp-includes/Requests/Utility/CaseInsensitiveDictionary.php on line 91
```

Please advice as to what could be possibly wrong with it.

Comment: Are you sure PHP 7.4 is the problem? What you're sharing is a PHP 8.1 issue, and one that has fixes in the upcoming WP 6.2

Comment: alternatively, you're using Requests v2 in a plugin or library despite WP itself using Requests v1, the two are not compatible. ( WP 6.2 upgrades Requests v2 to improve PHP 8.X support ). If it is a PHP version issue then downgrading to 7.4 would resolve this

Comment: Even though the errors are coming from WP Core, many times they come due to any third-party app (themes, plugins, etc.). To debug them a long time ago I prepared a [️ **debug checklist**](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/debug/info) that you can follow step-by-step to identify the source of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of warnings happen when you run WordPress v6.1 or lower on PHP v8.1+. You should downgrade PHP to v8.0, or wait for WordPress v6.2 which upgrades the Requests library to add compatibility with PHP 8.1. ( WP 6.2 at the time of writing is in the release candidate stages )

Note that these deprecations do not happen on PHP 7.4. I saw you said that they do, but this implies you didn't succesfully switch the site to PHP 7.4 and it may still be on PHP v8.1

Comment: How am I supposed to verify if the site is indeed running on PHP 7.4... I just went to the my hosting service PHP Configurator and changed

Comment: You can go to the Site Health Check page in the admin menus — `https://example.com/wp-admin/site-health.php`. If you don't see the PHP version, click the **Passed Tests** button, which should reveal, among other things, your server's PHP version.

Comment: WP site health, and plugins such as query monitor and others can tell you this directly within WP itself

Comment: Thanks. Can confirm I am running 8.1 even after being configured at 7.4... Any suggestions as to how I can force my site to use 7.4 Is there any programmatic method of selecting the PHP version.

Comment: not from within PHP, you'd have to ask your host as it usually requires changes to Nginx/Apache